# Docker and Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to get an existing docker app running on Windows 10.

**Problem 1:** When I install the docker toolbox, the Docker Quickstart Terminal is missing

**Problem 2:** When I run docker build, I get this error ERROR: Windows named pipe error: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Any ideas how to solve both errors?

**Note:** I was on Windows 10 Home - upgrading to Windows 10 pro and will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Windows 10 Pro and re-installing docker did the trick

Answer (score 4):

Reset Docker to factory defaults and logging into Docker console, sorted for me.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I tried EVERYTHING and this worked at once

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version `18.*` of docker, try uninstalling it and downgrade to version `17.*` (`v 17.12.0-ce`).

Alternatively, if that does not work and you are running on Windows using Mac with bootcamp and your Windows Virtualization does not seem to get enabled, you can try booting up on Mac OS and then on the explorer window go to File>Restart to restart the system back to Windows. This will somehow fix the Windows Virtualization setting back to Enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect the terminal you are using to the Docker deamon:

If you have bash installed, you can run:

```
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Otherwise from windows cmd, you can run

```
docker-machine.exe env --shell cmd default
```

Comment: Should the docker quickstart terminal not usually start this?

Comment: Isn't eval a *nix command? We're in windows context, this returns a "'eval' is not recognized" error.

Answer (score 1):

@Félix Gagnon-Grenier  - Windows 10 has a linux layer available - you can run bash in a powershell window, if you've got a certain upgrade to Windows 10 Pro.